# Json_table duplicate result data

Tags: mysql

Hello I just prepare the simplest case of my problem

```
select *
from
 orders,
 json_table(
  orders.items, '$[*]'
  columns(
    startDate datetime path '$.startDate'
  )
 ) as items
where
 (:todayStart is null or
 datediff(items.startDate, now()) = 0)
```

so generally query should return orders but when I pass value :todayStart then I search in orders.items array to any element in array has same startDate,
but problem is when :todayStart is null then query return duplicates values from orders like this:

[image]

So I think I should maybe run json_table only when :todayStart is not null (syntax error always), anyone have ide why json_table duplicate data?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share more data

Comment: @SelVazi I wanna to json_table not duplicate result data when :todayStart is null I tried something like this:

:todayStart is null or json_table ....
but always syntax error

Comment: Can you share your json value

Comment: it is just simple collections like this [{"startDate": "2023-01-01"}, {"startDate": "2023-01-03"}, {"startDate": "2023-01-02"}]